# Eclipse 3.7 (indigo SR2) m2e (1.1) import Maven will not add source folders of generated sources

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2e

I have a larger Maven (3.0.4) project which contains modules which have generated code like jaxb, javaws etc.

The problem I have is that after importing the projects the generated source path is not added as source folder in Eclipse. Currently i need to add the folder (target/generated-sources/jaxb) manually to get it working in Eclipse.

In older versions of m2e there existed a configuration which controls the phase which is run during the import.

Does someone have an idea which has to be changed?

**Update**
I have tested to add the source folder via the build-helper-maven-plugin

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>target/generated-sources/jaxb/</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But this doesn't solve the problem neither.

Comment: For this specific case, when typing the mvn eclipse:eclipse outside of eclipse it worked for me.

Comment: I never use eclipse:eclipse. Cause i'm using m2e inside eclipse. But that might be a good hint for that problem. I will check.

Comment: I also use m2e for 90% of my projects, but for two cases it does not work fine for me: *jaxb, xjc, jaxws, cxf-codegen... *warpath plugin (import of war including classes that should be part of classpath).

Comment: Try building the project outside eclipse first.  Nonexisting folders tend not to be added.

Answer (score 4):

You need the m2eclipse-buildhelper plugin to let m2e know how to add the new source folders.
If the version from

> Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open catalog...

doesn't install, try using this p2 update site to install it instead :

http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-buildhelper/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090124/

Answer (score 0):

Other than putting maven-controlled dependencies in the class path Maven seems to have backed away from updating project configurations.  This means that if you have Eclipse tools that require special project natures or class path configurations you will have to make those configuration changes yourself (or hope the tool does).

To support this m2e has added two eclipse extension points that an Eclipse plugin can extend.  These extensions will be called when the classpath and project description are being updated by maven.  And they're called only if you write an eclipse plugin that can be called.

There's a lot more detail, but that detail requires and understanding of eclipse plugin development.